# method for DNA extraction for human mucus(nose) or earwax?

Tags: dna-isolation

**What is a simple method for extracting human DNA from nose mucus or earwax?**

I tried googling for methods for DNA extraction for human nose mucus or earwax and couldn't find any. I assumed that if one can extract DNA from hair, which has few cells with non intact nucleus'  then the same could be done with earwax, which also has few cells or mucus? The simpler the method, the better, given I am an undergrad with low experience.

Comment: i dunno xD but how much in mass of "material" you have. You can purify  DNA from raw leaves from the plants for example, so I guess if you are able to homogeneize your sample and provided you have 1)the equipment and reagents necesary (isopropanol, ethanol, sterile water a centrifuge) and 2) there is simply enought DNA material in the sample to begin with you could give it a shot. Anyway I completely dont know, i d try it if google hasnt said otherwise i guess.. anyway SE i summon you

Comment: @Katz            I could wager i could collect the samples from my own nose and ear. And i do have access to those materials. So are you stating that a tradition extraction method for something like spit or hair would be suitable?

Comment: why do you want to do this btw xD

Comment: Just curious if I can do it as a side project, since I will have access to human primers for PCR and possibly have leftovers.

Comment: try oral mucosa as DNA source then, i am totally convinced that you should get routine protocols online to do that with PCR as a goal.

Comment: @Katz           I have a protocol for spit, id rather get something specifically for "boogers" and "earwax".

Comment: why? the DNA is the same so it wont matter to do PCR. anyway if it is a must, i guess as i said you can try with the classical DNa estraction method and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27405/discussion-between-ro-siv-and-katz).

Comment: im sorry just saw it, anyway im kinda busy and cant really. but anyway i dont have anymore to say i guess, just try it if you feel so and see what happens. good luck!